# Activity or Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm new in Android programming, researching and reading Android's manuals I've seen that you can use activities and fragments. I've understood that a fragment is a ¨small activity¨. 
For example, I can create an app with buttons that create new activities or I can create an app with only one activity that open a ¨main¨ fragment with buttons that replace that with another.
So my questions are: when is more convenient to use one or another? Can I get the same functionality? 
Another final question: I want my app to have a drawer similar to the Facebook app, is it a Fragment or a regular drawer with an effect?
Thanks a lot

Comment: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html. check the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually use both. A fragment cannot live without a hosting activity.

As as simple rule of thumb, use fragments everywhere that has a reusable or pluggable interface. Use activity on simple places that does not call for a fragment, such as splash screens.

For the facebook drawer thingy, this is it -> https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: Should I keep the functionality in the fragments and use activities for holding fragments only (so I can reuse code)?
That's the classic drawer that Google apps use, Facebook has another one that is quite different (it kind of slides the app) and also has a second drawer on the right that opens the messenger chat. Is the same drawer with an effect or is it something else?

Comment: That depends on your desired architecture. In my projects i usually keep the activity as the "functionality" and the fragments as the "views", then i create java interfaces that the fragment calls when a view is interacted with. The activity (with implements the given java intefaces) provide the desired functionality.

The advantage of this approach is that several fragments can interact with the same interfaces, that can be implemented by several activities etc.

Yes, is the same drawer object with custom code. You can write your animations, position and etc of your drawer based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments sit inside of activities so really you have to use just activities or both fragments and activities. I would use fragments.

You really need to read this until you understand it a bit more
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Should I keep the functionality in the fragments so I can use activities for holding fragments only? (so I can re use the fragments when changing layouts for example)

Comment: If you want to take a look at a finished app download the source for the Google IO app, this helped me when I was starting out https://code.google.com/p/iosched/